# Como actualizo la lista de un RecyclerView en tiempo real cuando inserto un registro en SQLite

Tags: java, android

Tengo una activity con un ViewPager y dentro tres fragments y desde el tercer fragment tengo un pequeño formulario y abajo un recyclerview que contiene los datos que guardo en el form de arriba, lo que intento hacer es que al guardar un registro el recyclerView se actualice en tiempo real, pero no lo he conseguido llevo semanas con este problema. Adjunto una imagen para que tenga idea de lo que digo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZODw.png estoy usando

Este es el Fragment

```
public class TarifaFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText edtTarifa;
TextView tvFecha;
ImageButton imgbtnFecha;
Button btnCrearTarifa;

// objeto helper para gestionar operaciones con la base de datos
DBHelper conn;

// Recycler para cargar la lista de registros almacenados en la base de datos
RecyclerView recyclerTarifas;
ArrayList<Tarifa> listaTarifas;
TarifaAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tarifa, container, false);

    // inicializar el bojeto conexion
    conn = new DBHelper(getActivity());
    listaTarifas = new ArrayList<>();

    imgbtnFecha = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnFecha);
    imgbtnFecha.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvFecha = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvFechaTarifa);
    edtTarifa = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtTarifa);
    btnCrearTarifa = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCrearTarifa);
    btnCrearTarifa.setOnClickListener(this);
    recyclerTarifas = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTarifa);
    // setear el layout para el recyclerView
    recyclerTarifas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    ConsultarListaTarfias();
    adapter = new TarifaAdapter(listaTarifas);
    recyclerTarifas.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

private void ConsultarListaTarfias()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
    Tarifa tarifa = null;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+Utils.NOMBRE_TABLATARIFA+" ORDER BY tarifaId DESC",null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        tarifa = new Tarifa();
        tarifa.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        tarifa.setTarifa(cursor.getString(1));
        tarifa.setFecha(cursor.getString(2));

        listaTarifas.add(tarifa);
    }
}

public void InsertarTarifa()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String tarifa = edtTarifa.getText().toString();
    String fechaTarifa = tvFecha.getText().toString();

    values.put(Utils.CAMPO_CANTIDADTARIFA,tarifa);
    values.put(Utils.CAMPO_FECHATARIFA,fechaTarifa);

    if(!(tarifa.equals("")) && !(fechaTarifa.equals("")) && !(fechaTarifa.equals("Fecha")))
    {
        long resultado = db.insert(Utils.NOMBRE_TABLATARIFA,Utils.CAMPO_TARIFAID,values);

        if(resultado != 0)
        {
            Log.i("Registro Creado",""+resultado);

            final SweetAlertDialog dialogo = new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(),SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
                    dialogo.setTitleText("EXITO!")
                    .setContentText("REGISTRO CREADO CORRECTAMENTE")
                    .setConfirmText("CONTINUAR")
                    .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                            dialogo.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            tvFecha.setText("Fecha");
            edtTarifa.setText("");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        final SweetAlertDialog dialogo = new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(),SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);
        dialogo.setTitleText("ERROR!")
                .setContentText("TODOS LOS CAMPOS SON REQUERIDOS")
                .setConfirmText("CONTINUAR")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        dialogo.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
    db.close();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.tvFechaTarifa:
            CrearDialogoFecha(v,getActivity(),getActivity().getFragmentManager());
            break;

        case R.id.imgbtnFecha:
            CrearDialogoFecha(v,getActivity(),getActivity().getFragmentManager());
            break;

        case R.id.btnCrearTarifa:
            InsertarTarifa();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Este es el código del Adapter

```
public class TarifaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TarifaAdapter.ViewHolderTarifa> {

ArrayList<Tarifa> listaTarifas;

public TarifaAdapter(ArrayList<Tarifa> listaTarifas)
{
    this.listaTarifas = listaTarifas;
}

@Override
public ViewHolderTarifa onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_tarifas,null,false);
    return new ViewHolderTarifa(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderTarifa holder, int position) {
    Tarifa tarifa = this.listaTarifas.get(position);
    //tarifa.getMySpecialStatus();
    holder.tvTarifa.setText("Q."+listaTarifas.get(position).getTarifa());
    holder.tvFechaTarifa.setText(listaTarifas.get(position).getFecha());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaTarifas.size();
}

public void update(ArrayList<Tarifa> modelList){
    this.listaTarifas.clear();
    for (Tarifa model: modelList) {
        this.listaTarifas.add(model);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void replaceItem(ArrayList<Tarifa> lista)
{
    this.listaTarifas.clear();
        if(lista != null)
        {
            this.listaTarifas.clear();
            this.listaTarifas.addAll(lista);
        }
        else
        {
            this.listaTarifas = lista;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ViewHolderTarifa extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTarifa, tvFechaTarifa;

    public ViewHolderTarifa(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvTarifa = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTarifa);
        tvFechaTarifa = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFechaTarifa);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: El metodo update y el metodo replaceItem que tengo en el adapter no me funcionan para lograr lo que necesito

Comment: utiliza notifiyDataSetChanged, se encarga de actualizar tu adapter

Comment: ya le usado pero no me funciona, en el adapter hago uso de el pero no me ha funcionado, no tengo muy claro donde usarlo, ya he probado llamando al metodo que contiene el notifyDataSetChanged en el onCreateView del Fragment o en el Evento onclick del botón que guarda el registro en la BD

Comment: crear un método para llamar a tu lista SQLite e invócalo en el onResume

Comment: ya tengo este metodo en el fragment para consultar y añadir al ArrayList el resultado de SQLite  se llama ConsultarListaTarfias()

Comment: pero no me funciona alguien podria darme un ejemplo detallado disculpen la molestia muchachos.

Comment: Yo tambien estoy sufriendo con eso ahora adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() tampoco me funciona, no se que hacer ya busque e intente pero no sale

Answer (score 1):

La semana pasada estaba viendo temas de persistencia con algunas librerías para SQLite

GreenDao:
https://github.com/marlonpya/Clean-GreenDao

Realm:
https://github.com/marlonpya/Standard-Android

**Para GreenDao**

Esto es lo que suelo hacer..
en mi actividad crear una **lista** desde el **sqlite** y setearla a mi **Adapter** en el **onResume**

**get list**

```
public List<UserSQL> getList() {
     return daoSession.queryBuilder(UserSQL.class).list();
}
```

**set list en Adapter**

```
public void load(List<UserBean> users){
     this.users = users;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**agregar un modelo**

```
public void add(UserBean user){
         this.users.add(user);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**agregar una lista**

```
public void addAll(List<UserBean> users) {
         this.users.addAll(users);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

sólo tendrías que crear una método para pasar de modelo SQL a Bean..

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    adapter.load(getList());
}
```

Comment: el recyclerView esta dentro de un fragment y lo lleno con un arrayList pero no funciona para mi lo que me dices ya que la lista no esta en una activity sino en un fragment, como haría en este caso?

Comment: el fragmento tmb tiene un onresume

Comment: si pero el onResume no se ejecuta nunca porque es en el mismo fragmento donde tengo el formulario y abajo del formulario el recyclerView con la lista de datos que se guardaron en el formulario de arriba

Comment: luego de tu método InsertarTarifa() agrega un adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: no funciona lo he puesto como me dices cuando presiono el boton crear se ejecuta el metodo InsertarTarfia() lo puse así
    case R.id.btnCrearTarifa:
                InsertarTarifa();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;

Comment: Estás actualizando la lista hasta ahí todo bien.. pero lo que se te olvida es actualizar el adapter. En pocas palabras deberías tener en el adapter un método para agregar items a tu lista.

Comment: acabo de actualizar si respuesta

Comment: podrias poner el ejemplo porfavor :(

Comment: revisa mi código en los repositorios q te he mandado.

Answer (score -1):

El problema que yo veo, es que no estas introduciendo a tu `ArrayList` los nuevos datos, por eso aun notificando cambios al adapter tal como dices haber intentado estos no se mostraran.
Prueba a hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
if(!(tarifa.equals("")) && !(fechaTarifa.equals("")) && !(fechaTarifa.equals("Fecha")))
{
    long resultado = db.insert(Utils.NOMBRE_TABLATARIFA,Utils.CAMPO_TARIFAID,values);

    if(resultado != 0)
    {
        Tarifa tarifaModelo = new Tarifa();
        tarifaModelo.setId(resultado);
        tarifaModelo.setTarifa(tarifa);
        tarifaModelo.setFecha(fechaTarifa);
        listaTarifas.add(tarifaModelo);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Log.i("Registro Creado",""+resultado);

        final SweetAlertDialog dialogo = new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(),SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
                dialogo.setTitleText("EXITO!")
                .setContentText("REGISTRO CREADO CORRECTAMENTE")
                .setConfirmText("CONTINUAR")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        dialogo.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
        tvFecha.setText("Fecha");
        edtTarifa.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: he probado lo que me dices, pero no funciona :(